# EWS SOAP request for scheduling a room with resource is not sending the meeting request to the resource

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to request a meeting in a particular room for a user. With the below SOAP request, I see that a tentative calendar event appears in the user's calendar, but nothing is showing up on the room calendar. How can I get the meeting request to send to the resource room? My goal is to have the room auto-reply to the meeting requester whether the meeting was accepted or declined based on the room's availability.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns1:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007"/>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns2:CreateItem SendMeetingInvitations="SendToAllAndSaveCopy">
        <ns2:Items>
            <ns1:CalendarItem>
                <ns1:ItemClass>IPM.Appointment</ns1:ItemClass>
                <ns1:Subject>Test Meeting</ns1:Subject>
                <ns1:Sensitivity>Normal</ns1:Sensitivity>
                <ns1:Importance>Normal</ns1:Importance>
                <ns1:Start>2018-12-29T06:00:00+00:00</ns1:Start>
                <ns1:End>2018-12-29T06:30:00+00:00</ns1:End>
                <ns1:RequiredAttendees>
                    <ns1:Attendee>
                        <ns1:Mailbox>
                            <ns1:Name>Bob Joe</ns1:Name>
                            <ns1:EmailAddress>sampleUser@website.com</ns1:EmailAddress>
                            <ns1:RoutingType>SMTP</ns1:RoutingType>
                        </ns1:Mailbox>
                    </ns1:Attendee>
                </ns1:RequiredAttendees>
                <ns1:Resources>
                    <ns1:Attendee>
                        <ns1:Mailbox>
                            <ns1:EmailAddress>sampleRoomEmail@website.com</ns1:EmailAddress>
                            <ns1:RoutingType>SMTP</ns1:RoutingType>
                        </ns1:Mailbox>
                    </ns1:Attendee>
                </ns1:Resources>
            </ns1:CalendarItem>
        </ns2:Items>
    </ns2:CreateItem>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Do you see the request in the resource's inbox? Make sure the mailbox is configured to auto accept the requests.

Answer (score -1):

You could use EWS Manage API, please refer to the below code:

```
        DateTime StartDate = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime EndDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(2);
        CalendarView cv = new CalendarView(StartDate, EndDate);
        String MailboxToAccess = "user@domain.com";
        FolderId CalendarFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, MailboxToAccess);
        FindItemsResults<Appointment> fapts = service.FindAppointments(CalendarFolderId, cv);
        if (fapts.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Appointment Appoint in fapts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Appoint.Start);
                Console.WriteLine(Appoint.Subject);
            }
        }
```

For more information, please refer to these links:

[Get all appointments from a resource(room) in Exchange Online(2010) with EWS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/440926e7-1f1c-4f1e-8f23-7971fe3867b9/get-all-appointments-from-a-resourceroom-in-exchange-online2010-with-ews?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment)

[Resources in Exchange don't respond to meeting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2005631/resources-in-exchange-don-t-respond-to-meeting-requests)